# Creating Data Frame form a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, nlp

I need to create a dataframe from a loop. the idea is that the loop will read a data frame of texts (train_vs) and search for specific key words ['govern', 'data'] and then calculate their frequency or TF. what I want is an outcome of two columns with the TF of the words for each text inside them. the code I am using is the following:

```
d = pd.DataFrame()
key = ['govern', 'data']
for k in key:
    for w in range(0, len(train_vs)):
        wordcount = Counter(train_vs['doc_text'].iloc[w])
        a_vs = (wordcount[k]/len(train_v.iloc[w])*1)
        temp = pd.DataFrame([{k: a_vs}] )
        d = pd.concat([d, temp])
```

however, I am getting two columns but with values for the first key word and nan for second for the whole texts column and then nan for the first and values for the second again for the whole texts column. so the number of the rows of the outcome dataframe is double.

I want to have both values next to each other.
Your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) documentation:

> Combine DataFrame objects with overlapping columns and return everything. Columns outside the intersection will be filled with NaN values.

What you are doing, when loop with the key changes is to try and concatenate a new df (temp) that has a single column(`'data'`) to the old df that also has a single column (`'gonvern'`) and that's why you get the half columns of NANs.

What you could do instead of concatenating millions of dataframes is to build only one dataframe, by building the columns.

```
d = pd.DataFrame()
key = ['govern', 'data']
for k in key:
    column = []
    for w in range(0, len(train_vs)):
        wordcount = Counter(train_vs['doc_text'].iloc[w])
        a_vs = (wordcount[k] / len(train_v.iloc[w]) * 1)
        column.append(a_vs)
    d[k] = column
```

Comment: This seems to work. thanks a lot for the code and the info.

Comment: If the answer solves your question you should mark it as the answer as to close the question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work